# When is the displacement 16bit in x86 64-bit mode?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, intel

In intel x86 developer's manual:

Volume1-3.7.5.1 said displacement can be 8,16,32bit in 64-bit mode.

But Volume2-2.2.1.3 said displacement can only be 8 or 32bit in 64-bit mode.

So, which is right?
Or this is a bug of the manual?

Comment: You can't have a 16 bit displacement, so I'd say V1 is wrong.

Comment: The address size override prefix in 64bit mode means that 32bit addressing will be used, there is no new prefix to use 16bit addressing from 64bit mode. And 16bit offsets only exist in 16bit addressing.

Comment: So, is this a bug of the manual?

Comment: It is, and far from the only one..